# Why cant I connect to New Relic with Python?

Tags: python, newrelic

I'm trying to monitor my python application with new relic, I'm following the simple guide for new relic after clicking "add more data".

Last step is to run your script with:

```
NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE=newrelic.ini newrelic-admin run-program $YOUR_COMMAND_OPTIONS
```

This will then check for data, but for me it doesnt find any data to check for and i cant connect to new relic?

Why can this be?

Comment: How do u know its not connected? or that there is no data? Unless u show us sm logs or error messages, no one can help u on this

Comment: In step 5 when setting up my Python Application in New Relic UI: "Check for data -
Click the button and give us a few minutes or less. We’ll let you know when we’ve received your data and where you can see it."

It just searches for data to monitor. I do run NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE=newrelic.ini newrelic-admin run-program python3 app.py which has a simple hello world log.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

I didn't work inside my virtual env, that's why i couldn't connect to NewRelic! (I'm new to python) :D